# Show : $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ is absolutely convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Given $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is absolutely convergent. Show that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ also converges absolutely. (If $a_n \neq -1, \forall n \geq 1$ )

I am not sure where to start with this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You know $a_n\to0$. So there exists $N$ such that $a_n>-1/2$ for all $n>N$...

Answer (score 0):

We have: $\dfrac{|a_n|}{|1+a_n|}\leq \dfrac{|a_n|}{1-|a_n|}\leq \dfrac{|a_n|}{1-\frac{1}{2}}= 2|a_n| $  for all $n \geq N_0$ since $a_n \to 0$, and using comparison test, the conclusion follows.

Comment: I understand the above inequality, but how do we know 2|an| is convergent. If |an|<1/2 then 2|an| is < 1. How does this prove convergence?

Comment: If $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n |a_k| \to L \implies \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n 2|a_k| \to 2L$

Answer (score 0):

From the fact that $\sum_n |a_n|$ converges, one has that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$. Then you can use the limit comparison test, comparing ${\displaystyle \sum_n \bigg|{a_n \over 1 + a_n}\bigg|}$ to $\sum_n |a_n|$, to show that your series is absolutely convergent, and therefore convergent.

Comment: Using the limit comparison test, I would get lim n→∞[ an/(1+an)] / an. Which is equal to lim 1/(1+an). Since an -> 0 then the limit of 1/(1+an) =1 so the series an/(1+an) converges. Is this correct?

Comment: It's right, except you should put everything in absolute values, since the limit comparison test applies only to series with nonnegative terms.